# Neo 6M + ESP32 unable to take a fix on battery but works fine with laptop USB

Tags: esp32, gps

I am using Neo 6M GPS module with ESP32 and 2 X 3.5V(7 v in series) 18650 lithium ion battery stepped down to 5V using LM2596 buck converter.

Problem which I am facing is when I power ESP32 using 5V output of LM2596 by connecting Vin pin and powering Neo6M using 5V output of buck converter or 3.3 V of ESP32 then my Neo 6M is unable to fix on satellite, however when removing battery and LM2596 and powering ESP32 using laptop usb cable and Neo 6M using 3V pin of ESP32 then its able to take a fix in 1 minute.

Any idea what mistake I could be doing.
Note - When using battery ESP32 is working as normal and able to connect to wifi and submit Tiny GPS++ output everysecond.

Please let me know in case more information required.

Answer (score 0):

With full battery charge to 3.7V this issue was resolved also using 10uf capacitor between vcc and ground help to improve

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. You are telling me it is power related as the ESP runs fine but the Neo 6M failed. Reason the Neo 6M does not tolerate as wide a voltage range as the ESP32. Using a Buck converter is a mistook, you should use a SEPIC (bicl/boost in one), this will maintain the voltage to your project as the battery voltage changes with its charge etc. With the correct SEPIC converter you can parallel the batteries giving you more instantaneous current. The buck converter needs head room, that is so much voltage above the output to work properly. I doubt it is less than 2v. Using small wires will esterbate your problems. The 10uF was a good idea but you also want to add something for high frequency. This should get you going.